# MySql allow null in JOIN and SUM

Tags: mysql

Guys i have documents (orders) and products, when i listing orders i create new column with name TOTAL to sum total price of the products in order. If order does not have products it should show zero in sum column.
This query work if document have products in **document_items** but if not have row not showed in result.
I try to use **COALEASE** to show 0 if is null but again not work. How i can achive this?

**Here is my code:**

```
SELECT
     d.id,
     d.number,
     dt.name AS type,
     sbj.name AS supplier,
     s.name AS stock,
     d.status,
     COALESCE(SUM(ds.qty * ds.price), 0) AS total, # here is problem if is null show 0
     d.created_at AS created_at
FROM documents AS d
INNER JOIN subject AS sbj ON sbj.id = d.subject_id
INNER JOIN stock AS s ON s.id = d.stock_id
INNER JOIN document_type AS dt ON dt.id = d.document_type_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN document_items ds ON ds.document_id = d.id # and here is problem
ORDER BY d.id DESC;
```

When i remove this two commented lines that will work.

**Tables**

```
Document
--------------------------------------
id               INT(11)     PK    AI    NotNull
number           VARCHAR
subject_id        INT(11)
stock_id          INT(11)
document_type_id  INT(11)
status            TYNIYINT


Stock
--------------------------------------
id           INT(11)     PK    AI    NotNull
name         VARCHAR


Stock
--------------------------------------
id           INT(11)     PK    AI    NotNull
name         VARCHAR


Product
--------------------------------------
id           INT(11)     PK    AI    NotNull
name         VARCHAR
```

DocumentItems
--------------------------------------
id            INT(11)     PK    AI    NotNull
document_id   INT(11)
product_id    INT(11)
qty           INT(11)
price         DECIMAL

Comment: pls post som json object to verify it

Comment: I post update abve

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
SELECT
     d.id,
     d.number,
     dt.name AS type,
     sbj.name AS supplier,
     s.name AS stock,
     d.status,
     COALESCE(SUM(ds.qty * ds.price), 0) AS total,
     d.created_at AS created_at
FROM documents AS d
INNER JOIN subject AS sbj ON sbj.id = d.subject_id
INNER JOIN stock AS s ON s.id = d.stock_id
INNER JOIN document_type AS dt ON dt.id = d.document_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN document_items ds ON ds.document_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.id, d.number, dt.name, sbj.name, s.name, d.status, d.created_at
ORDER BY d.id DESC;
```

Comment: This works thanks. So pont is in the GROUP By